# Не удается создать виртуальное окружение в poetry

Tags: python, poetry

**Установлены python 3.11.2, poetry 1.4.2, добавлены в PATH.**

Не удается создать виртуальное окружение командой `poetry env use ***`. На месте *** пробовал:

- C:/users/Илья/appdata/local/programs/python/python311/ (путь к папке
  с python) - ошибка `[WinError 5] Отказано в доступе`
- C:/users/Илья/appdata/local/programs/python/python311/python.exe
  (путь к самому python)
- python3.11
- python3.11.2
- python
- 3.11
- 3.11.2

В остальных случаях ошибка `[WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл`

Регистр не имеет значения, пробовал по разному.

Запускал от имени администратора, чтобы не было ошибки об отказе в доступе - не помогает.

Comment: А если просто попробовать запустить все упомянутые python-команды без poetry - они запускаются хотя бы?

Comment: @andreymal, без poetry python запускается, как по абсолютному пути, так и командой. В каталог с python получается перейти, не смотря на то, что папка AppData скрытая в windows.

Comment: Попробуйте запустить poetry с опцией `-vvv` вдруг в отладочных логах что-нибудь полезное напишет

Comment: @andreymal, может быть проблема в кириллице в пути к файлу питона? Он находится в "C:/users/Илья/appdata/local/programs/python/python311", но если выполнить "poetry env info", кодировка ломается на "Илья", в одном пути poetry показывает "╨Ш╨╗╤М╤П", в другом - "Èëüÿ", хотя руками виртуальная оболочка активируется.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь использовать окружение, не создав его.
Для создания окружения:

1. Заходим в нужную папку для создания проекта:

   `cd C:\Users\username\project`
2. Создаем новый проект:

   `poetry new first`
3. Заходим в папку проекта:

   `cd first`

   в этой папке будет лежать файл pyproject.toml - это конфигурация проекта

А для указания в poetry какую версию python использовать можно использовать один из этих методов:

- Указать полный путь: `poetry env use /full/path/to/python`
- Если файл указан в PATH: `poetry env use python3.7`
- Используя системную версию: `poetry env use system`
- Ещё один вариант использования: `poetry env use 3.7`

Для полного понимания советую почитать документацию, например: как создавать, выводить информацию; подгружать необходимые библиотеки; конфигурировать окружение.

Comment: Вроде бы poetry всегда сам создаёт окружение

Comment: @andreymal вы написали "Не удается создать виртуальное окружение командой poetry env use ***" - команда нужна для указания версии , а не для создания окружения.